# Warning of duplicates in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am working on a MS-Access database to keep track of last names and addresses and several other records. I am making a table and would like for it to be updated by the user by inputting info from a form. The question I have is can I have several key items that would warn if a duplicate is found. Mainly if a duplicate is found in the last name and the address fields. I need the form to accept the duplicate because how the info is being obtained duplicates are possible but need to be able to enter the duplicate and warn the user while entering the data that a previous entry has already been made that is similar.

Is this possible in Access, and easy to implement that many different users may be entering the data? I haven't used Access for some time, sorry if I'm not using the correct terms, as I'm still learning the basics of Access, as I mainly work in Excel. Excel is the current solution that is being used, but finding quickly that a better solution is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the several solutions. I'm finding that Access might not be up for the job. I keep getting warned that Access is not the correct program to use. Would anyone suggest a better program to use? -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Names aren't good candidates for primary keys and it seems that you have set the name as the primary key of one of your tables. You should either use a better candidate key (social insurance number, for example) or create a surrogate (artificial, if you want) key with no meaning other than being a key for your table.

Without more detail about your table structure it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I would rather use a number but a last name and street address is the only consistent item that I am able to obtain to track a person as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Warn the user but allow her to proceed if she wishes?

If so, a key constraint would be too, ahem, *constraining*. Just check for the duplicates manually (by explicitly querying existing data from your code). You may wish to index the field(s) being searched.

Comment: I thought of just having the person run a report each time a record is entered, but was hoping there was an easier solution. Something that would let the user see if a record was similar while they were entering it into Access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can validate through this code:

```
If Nz(DCount("FieldName", "table", "FieldName= '" & Me.FieldName.Value & "'"), 0) > 0 Then
     If MsgBox("The FieldName already exist", vbOKCancel, "Duplicate Warning") = vbCancel Then Cancel = True
         Me.Undo
         Exit Sub
     End If 
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

In general terms, Access (and relational databases generally) are about preventing duplicate data from being entered in the first place. If you merely want to 'warn', then it will take a bit of custom code. So, say the table is called `Customers` and it has fields such as `CustomerID` (AutoNumber, primary key) and `LastName` (Text). The form then has a text box called `txtLastName` that is bound to the `LastName` field. In this situation, you could handle the text box's `BeforeUpdate` event like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const DuplicateWarningTitle = "Duplicate Record"
Const DuplicateValueWarning = "A record already exists with " + _
  "the value you have entered. Are you sure you want to continue?"

Function GetSQLLiteral(Value As Variant) As String
  Select Case VarType(Value)
    Case vbNull
      GetSQLLiteral = "Null"
    Case vbString
      GetSQLLiteral = "'" + Replace(Value, "'", "''") + "'"
    Case Else
      GetSQLLiteral = CStr(Value)
  End Select
End Function

Sub HandleKeyFieldBeforeUpdate(Control As Access.TextBox, Cancel As Integer)
  Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT 1 FROM Customers " + _
    "WHERE " + Control.ControlSource + " = " + GetSQLLiteral(txtLastName.Value) + _
    " AND CustomerID <> " & Me.CustomerID)
  If Not RS.EOF Then
    Select Case MsgBox(DuplicateValueWarning, vbExclamation + vbYesNo, DuplicateWarningTitle)
      Case vbYes
        ' just proceed
      Case vbNo
        Cancel = True
        Control.Undo ' if desired!
    End Select
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtLastName_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  HandleKeyFieldBeforeUpdate txtLastName, Cancel
End Sub
```

By pushing the duplicate checking code into a generic helper routine, other key fields can be handled in the same way easily:

```
Private Sub txtAddress_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  HandleKeyFieldBeforeUpdate txtAddress, Cancel
End Sub
```

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - er, at least I answered the question asked, unlike you. Moreover, the context is Access (and in particular, Access-as-Excel-replacement), so using an ad hoc parameterised query is not very convenient and (IMO) not worth the effort. By all means enlighten me to the contrary however - what sort of attack are you thinking of?

Comment: The accidental one. Your program should handle every user input robustly, and this is not the case here. Furthermore, bound parameters are not just about injection attacks - they can also benefit performance.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - like what? I stand by the code as suitable for the context, and I really don't see where your supposed performance improvement is going to emerge, given the tools available.

Comment: How would I go about testing this solution in Access, or executing the code?

Comment: @buzlink - not sure what you mean. Are you asking how to create an event handler in Access, or how to create unit tests for an Access project?